# CHOLMOD sparse dense multiplication issue

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication, suitesparse

I am testing out cholmod to solve a sparse matrix system. As b of the Ax=b equation I want to use something that will lead to a known result, so I choose to declare as xe a vector of ones and b=A*xe.

I tried some different approaches to do the sparse-matrix dense-vector multiplication without any success.
As first test I am using the ex15 matrix from [SuitSparse matrix collection](https://sparse.tamu.edu/FIDAP/ex15)

```
#include "cholmod.h"
#include <iostream>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
int main()
{
    const char* matFile = "C:/www/CholeskyMatGPU/ex15.mtx";
    const char* bfile = "C:/www/CholeskyMatGPU/b.mtx";
    FILE* bp = fopen(bfile, "w");
    FILE* fp = fopen(matFile, "r");
    cholmod_sparse *A;
    cholmod_dense *x, *xe, *b;
    cholmod_factor *L;

    cholmod_common* c = (cholmod_common*)malloc(sizeof(cholmod_common));
    cholmod_l_start(c); /* start CHOLMOD */
    c->useGPU = 0;
    c->supernodal = CHOLMOD_SUPERNODAL;

    A = cholmod_l_read_sparse(fp, c); /* read in a matrix */
    cholmod_l_print_sparse(A, "A", c); /* print the matrix */
    fclose(fp);

    double alpha[2] = { 1., 0. };
    double beta[2] = { 0., 0. };
    xe = cholmod_l_ones(A->nrow, 1, A->xtype, c); 
    b = cholmod_l_allocate_dense(A->nrow, 1, A->nrow, CHOLMOD_LONG, c); //attempt1
    b = cholmod_copy_dense(xe, c); //attempt2
    b = cholmod_l_zeros(A->nrow, 1, A->xtype, c); //attempt3
    cholmod_sdmult(A, 0, alpha, beta, xe, b, c); //b = A*xe
    cholmod_l_write_dense(bp, b, "", c);
    L = cholmod_l_analyze(A, c); /* analyze */
    cholmod_l_factorize(A, L, c); /* factorize */
    x = cholmod_l_solve(CHOLMOD_A, L, b, c); /* solve Ax=b */
}
```

I expect b to be the result of the A*xe operation, so something like

```
-4487487.55116591
228083519.121975
0.0561846979753665
18213301.5299736
...
30383411.1062435
8073.91311889887
0.00602254606925790
-7101038.89577146
378419792.843878
0.0931721845637848
```

(checked from matlab)
but the shown code will print a vector of zeros, there is something wrong with what I am doing with sdmult.

```
A = Problem.A;
n = length(A);
xe(1:n,1) = 1;
b=A*xe;
R=chol(A);
tmp=(R'\b);
x=R\tmp;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was an increadibly stupid mistake, there isn't the long prefix in the method name!
This won't throw any error but it won't execute the multiplication.
With `cholmod_l_sdmult(A, 0, alpha, beta, xe, b, c);` instead of `cholmod_sdmult(A, 0, alpha, beta, xe, b, c);` everything works fine..